# How to flush CUPS spool

Tags: printing

My printer is blocking; there is no relevant message in the error log, but the printer dialog says: "/var/spool/cups/d00359-001 (object 89 0, file position 957134): expected endobj"

I deleted that file but that didn't change anything.

This happened after trying to print a latex-generated pdf (3.5MB)

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to delete the printer configuration and retrying as a new printer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Well, I posted it as a comment, but I will post it as a answer.*

Maybe deleting the printer will reset the stack and solve the error.

*My computer system is in Spanish, but the icons are very clear to do the steps*

1. Go to System Configuration -> Printers
   [image]
2. Delete the printer that is having the error
   [image]
3. Unplug the printer an plug it again to configure it as a new printer
4. Try to print

Answer (score 2):

I would try and **avoid** *deleting/adding* a printer if possible. This link has a thorough answer to your question and provides a *cleaner/ alternate* method to resolving your issue:

[Is there an approved way to clear /var/cups/cache on a Unix system?](https://superuser.com/questions/155933/is-there-an-approved-way-to-clear-var-cups-cache-on-a-unix-system)