# Printer Canon Pixma iP 4500 not printing - stoping at page processing

Tags: printing, canon

I have a Pixma iP 4500 just stopped printing, it's just processing the page stops at 1,24%. Being a total noob, here is part troubleshoot output (I couldn't paste the whole file), please let me know if you need some additional data and how/where should I find them so I can post them (thanks):

```
{'cups_connection_failure': False}
Page 2 (Choose printer):
{'cups_dest': <cups.Dest Canon-iP4500-series (default)>,
 'cups_instance': None,
 'cups_queue': 'Canon-iP4500-series',
 'cups_queue_listed': True}
Page 3 (Check printer sanity):
{'cups_device_uri_scheme': u'usb',
 'cups_printer_dict': {'device-uri': u'usb://Canon/iP4500%20series?serial=323BCC',
                       'printer-info': u'Canon iP4500 series',
                       'printer-is-shared': False,
                       'printer-location': u'maja-PC',
                       'printer-make-and-model': u'Canon PIXMA iP4500 - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.7 Simplified',
                       'printer-state': 4,
                       'printer-state-message': u'Printing page 1, 14%',
                       'printer-state-reasons': [u'none'],
                       'printer-type': 2273308,
                       'printer-uri-supported': u'ipp://localhost:631/printers/Canon-iP4500-series'},
 'cups_printer_remote': False,
 'is_cups_class': False,
 'local_cups_queue_attributes': {'auth-info-required': u'none',
                                 'charset-configured': u'utf-8',
                                 'charset-supported': [u'us-ascii', u'utf-8'],
                                 'color-supported': True,
                                 'compression-supported': [u'none', u'gzip'],
                                 'copies-default': 1,
                                 'copies-supported': (1, 9999),
                                 'cups-version': u'1.5.0',
                                 'device-uri': u'usb://Canon/iP4500%20series?serial=323BCC',
                                 'document-format-default': u'application/octet-stream',
                                 'document-format-supported': [u'application/octet-stream',
                                                               u'application/openofficeps',
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this two answers:

First one I would try is this: https://superuser.com/a/155950/221323

> According to [CUPS documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpq4x.png), the [standard config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwBNV.png) places
>   cache files in */var/spool/cups/cache* and print jobs in
>   */var/spool/cups*.  I'd imagine the best strategy is either of the following:
>
> 1. Clear it with specific CUPS commands.  Unfortunately there's not a builtin command to clear the cache; only enabling/disabling specific
>      print queues and removing specific print jobs seem to be
>      available.
>    Use [lpq](http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/doc-1.4/man-lpq.html) (to view the queues), [lprm](http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/doc-1.4/man-lprm.html), and
>      [cancel](http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/doc-1.4/man-cancel.html), or the web interface, to view current jobs and remove
>      them.  `cancel -a` should cancel all jobs on all queues.
>    If
>      your system is hosed by defined printers and queues, deleting those
>      objects may help.  Use [lpadmin](http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/doc-1.4/man-lpadmin.html) or the web interface to manage
>      defined printers.
> 2. Clear it manually, by:
>
>    1. stopping CUPS (eg, `sudo service cups stop`),
>    2. removing files manually, and
>    3. restarting CUPS (eg, `sudo service cups start`).
>
> [This long thread](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/how-to-clear-cups-server-564866/) suggests that */var/spool/cups* contains
>   completed print jobs while */var/spool/cups/tmp* contains in-progress
>   jobs. One post to that thread suggests running `sudo rm -r
>   /var/spool/cups` in step 2.2 above.  Steps 2.1 and 2.3 show Ubuntu
>   commands for stopping and starting services; other OS's will vary.
>
> If you really need to delete cache files in */var/cache/cups*, you
>   will probably need to use the manual method.

And the second one is this: https://askubuntu.com/a/303604/153260

> *Well, I posted it as a comment, but I will post it as a answer.*
>
> Maybe deleting the printer will reset the stack and solve the error.
>
> *My computer system is in Spanish, but the icons are very clear to do the steps*
>
> 1. Go to System Configuration -> Printers [image]
> 2. Delete the printer that is having the error [image]
> 3. Unplug the printer an plug it again to configure it as a new printer
> 4. Try to print

Comment: /var/spool/cups/tmp was empty, but when trying to open the folder I have no permission to open it. Deleting the printer didn't do the job either :(

Comment: /var/spool/cups/tmp was empty; I suppose permissions have no difference here :)

Comment: And did you try the second option?

Comment: yes, it didn't help. He is still processing the test page, doesn't print anything. Too bad I can not post the whole troubleshoot file. Maybe something can be seen there...